# Tailwind CSS not working with Next JS 12, but works with Next JS 11

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I've set up tailwind css for my project with next js v12. I've set up purging and file imports accordingly and it should style the components/pages correctly. However.. It doesn't. No errors or anything. But when I rollback to Next JS v11, the styling gets applied when I don't change any code.
I'm failing to understand why this is an issue for me as it seems it's not a common issue.

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: 'false', // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

globals.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


@layer base {
  html,
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
}
```

_app.tsx

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";

import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to restart my damn application for the config to compile when I made changes to it.